# Setting specific compile flags for projects in CMake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I've managed to edit link flags for specific projects using:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${target} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/foo")
```

but I can't seem to edit the compiler flags using:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${target} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/bar")
```

On opening the Visual Studio project I can't find "/bar" under the command line options. I have tried replacing "/bar" with a real flag but I can't see any changes happening under the C/C++ configuration properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out I need to move these functions after adding the executable to CMake